# Hiding ip camera credentials in source code

Tags: camera, ip, rtsp, ip-camera

I have embedded an IP camera feed on my company's public webpage using a VLC plugin. Part of the source code includes the username, password and ip address of the camera by using an RTSP feed. Is there a way to "hide" this code so users cannot just look at my source code and have the credentials to my ip camera?

Would it be possible for someone to hack into my IP camera using these credentials?

Comment: Always assume that a hack is possible!

Comment: The RTSP source is exposed in your webpage html and you can't hide it, you maybe could restrict access by client to your company webpage (Surely you don't want it) but html always will be exposed in clients. About hacking your camera, the username and password for accesing stream should be different to username and password for accesing your camera manager. You can configure credentials for streams by the cam manager sofware.